# XlsxWriter - setting gridlines color

Tags: python, excel, colors, xlsxwriter

I'm wondering if one can set the color for major or minor gridlines when adding charts.

The documentation shows an example of setting `'visible' : True/False` and `'dash_style'`, but when I pass a parameter for `'color'` there is no change.

I assume the gridline instance of 'line' does not have a 'color' parameter, but am asking in case I'm missing the solution.

```
chart.set_x_axis({
    'major_gridlines': {
        'visible': True,
        'line': {'width': 1.25, 'dash_type': 'dash', 'color' : 'red'}
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted should work as expected.

Here is the code in a working example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})


worksheet.write_column('A1', [5, 4, 9, 12, 7])

chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})

chart.set_x_axis({
    'major_gridlines': {
        'visible': True,
        'line': {'width': 1.25, 'dash_type': 'dash', 'color' : 'red'}
    },
})

worksheet.insert_chart('A7', chart)

workbook.close()
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jmcnamara! I see my error (had used 'colour' in the code I was testing instead of 'color'). Appreciate your quick response and thank you for such a wonderful and well documented library.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth making some aliases to handle British spellings, the way `xlwt` does. Not a high priority, of course.